# If $ab-1$, $bc-1$, $ca-1$, $ab-a-b+c$, $bc-b-c+a$, $ca-c-a+b$ are perfect squares, then are $ab+a+b-c$, $bc+b+c-a$, $ca+c+a-b$ also perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers

About a month ago, a friend of mine taught me that there exist many sets of three **positive integers** $(a,b,c)$ where $a\not=b,b\not=c$ and $c\not=a$ such that each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
is a **perfect square**.

Then, I found that there exist **infinitely many** such sets. For example, for $$(a,b,c)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1},F_{2n+3})$$
where $F_k$ is the $k$-th Fibonacci number defined by $F_0=0,F_1=1,F_{k}=F_{k-2}+F_{k-1}\ (k\ge 2)$,  we have
$$\color{red}{ab-1}=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}-1=\color{blue}{{F_{2n}}^2}$$ 
$$\color{red}{bc-1}=F_{2n+1}F_{2n+3}-1=\color{blue}{{F_{2n+2}}^2}$$ 
$$\color{red}{ca-1}=F_{2n+3}F_{2n-1}-1=F_{2n}F_{2n+2}+1=\color{blue}{{F_{2n+1}}^2}$$ 
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{ab-a-b+c}&=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}-F_{2n-1}-F_{2n+1}+F_{2n+3}\\&={F_{2n}}^2+1-F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+2}\\&={F_{2n}}^2+1+2F_{2n}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n}+1)^2}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{bc-b-c+a}&=F_{2n+1}F_{2n+3}-F_{2n+1}-F_{2n+3}+F_{2n-1}\\&={F_{2n+2}}^2+1-F_{2n+3}-F_{2n}\\&={F_{2n+2}}^2+1-2F_{2n+2}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n+2}-1)^2}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{ca-c-a+b}&=F_{2n+3}F_{2n-1}-F_{2n+3}-F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+1}\\&={F_{2n+1}}^2+1-F_{2n-1}-F_{2n+2}\\&={F_{2n+1}}^2+1-2F_{2n+1}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n+1}-1)^2}\end{align}$$

I have also found many other such sets which are not included in this Fibonacci family, and...

> Interestingly enough, for every set $(a,b,c)$ I found, each of 
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is also a perfect square.

For example, for $(a,b,c)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1},F_{2n+3})$, we have
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{ab+a+b-c}&=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}+F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+1}-F_{2n+3}\\&={F_{2n}}^2+1+F_{2n-1}-F_{2n+2}\\&={F_{2n}}^2+1-2F_{2n}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n}-1)^2}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{bc+b+c-a}&=F_{2n+1}F_{2n+3}+F_{2n+1}+F_{2n+3}-F_{2n-1}\\&={F_{2n+2}}^2+1+F_{2n+3}+F_{2n}\\&={F_{2n+2}}^2+1+2F_{2n+2}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n+2}+1)^2}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{ca+c+a-b}&=F_{2n+3}F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+3}+F_{2n-1}-F_{2n+1}\\&={F_{2n+1}}^2+1+F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+2}\\&={F_{2n+1}}^2+1+2F_{2n+1}\\&=\color{blue}{(F_{2n+1}+1)^2}\end{align}$$

So, here is my question.

> **Question** : Are the following propositions true?
>
> **Proposition 1 (False)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $a\not=b,b\not=c$ and $c\not=a$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
>   is a perfect square, then each of
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is a perfect square.
>
> **Proposition 2 (True)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{1\le} a\lt b\lt c$ and $ab+a+b-c\ge 0$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
>   is a perfect square, then each of
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is a perfect square.
>
> **Proposition 3** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{2\le} a\lt b\lt c$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
>   is a perfect square, then each of
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is a perfect square.
>
> **Proposition 4 (True)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{1\le} a\lt b\lt c$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab\mp (a+ b-c),\ bc\mp (b+ c- a),\ ca\mp (c+ a-b)$$
>   is a perfect square, then $c=a+b+2\sqrt{ab-1}$ holds.

**Added** : Proposition 1 is false because of $(a,b,c)=(1,5,65)$ found by Oleg567. Then, I added proposition 2 and 3. Also, I added proposition 4 (see Tito Piezas III's answer).

Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196609/conjectures-on-perfect-squares).

**Added** : Proposition 2 and 4 are true (see my answer for the details). However, we still don't know if proposition 3 is true.

Comment: $(a,b,c):$$(1,5,65)$, $(1,2,145)$, $(1,10,325)$, ... have $ab+a+b-c<0$, and $bc+b+c-a$ is not perfect square.

Comment: @Oleg567: You are right... So, the proposition is false. Thanks!

Comment: If $a<b<c$, then all my counterexamples have $a=1$ so far (up to $c\approx 100\;000$). Maybe if add condition that all $ab+a+b-c$  are non-negative, then ???

Comment: @Oleg567: That's interesting. So, another interesting question would be "For $2\le a\lt b\lt c\in\mathbb N$ if the six numbers are perfect squares, then are the three numbers perfect squares?" Anyway, you can write the counterexamples as an answer so that I can accept it to finish this question.

Comment: If I will find counterexamples with $a>1$ and/or all $ab+a+b-c, bc+b+c-a, ca+c+a-b$ non-negative, I'll write it as an answer :)

Comment: @Oleg567: Thanks:) I'm very interested in the question I wrote in my comment.

Comment: @Oleg567: I added proposition 2,3,4. I hope that you have not found any other counterexamples yet:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***(Update.)*** A quick search of,

$$\begin{aligned}
ab-1\;&=d^2\\
ac-1\;&=e^2\\
bc-1\;&=f^2
\end{aligned}$$

with $1<a<b<c$ gives,

$$2,\;5,\;13\\2,\;13,\;25\\2,\;25,\;41\\5,\;10,\;29\\5,\;13,\;34\\5,\;29,\;58$$
Certain patterns are immediately apparent. One of which is that the first 100 solutions with $c$ below a bound (and even higher) ***ALL*** satisfy,

$$(a+b+c)^2 = 2(a^2+b^2+c^2+2)\tag1$$

Equivalently (by solving for $c$),

$$c=a+b\pm2\sqrt{ab-1}=a+b\pm 2d$$

This has implications for the original proposition by the OP. (The first solution that does not satisfy the relation is $2,\,5,\,925.$)

**I. Assumption 1.**

There is a missing assumption in the Question section. It suffices to find two integers $a,b$ such that,

$$ab-1 = d^2\tag{2a}$$

then define $c$ as,

$$\color{blue}{c = a + b - 2 d}\tag{2b}$$

and these two conditions are sufficient to ensure that the following nine expressions necessarily are squares,

$$\begin{aligned}
a b-1\; &= d^2\\ 
a c-1\; &= (a - d)^2\\
b c-1 \; &=  (b - d)^2\\ 
a b - a - b + c \; &=  (1 - d)^2\\
b c + a - b - c  \; &=  (1 - b + d)^2\\ 
a c - a + b - c  \; &=  (1 - a + d)^2\\ 
a b +  a + b - c \; &=  (1 + d)^2\\ 
b c - a + b + c \; &=  (1 + b - d)^2\\ 
a c + a - b + c \; &=  (1 + a - d)^2
\end{aligned}$$

There are broad families to the 2 conditions. One is $a,\,b,\,c = x-ny,\;x+ny,\;2(x+my)$ where $x,y$ solve the *Pell equation*,

$$x^2-(m^2+n^2)y^2 = 1$$

This covers the Fibonacci family by the OP which was just the case $m,n= 2,1.$ (See also this similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136078/4781).)

**II. Assumption 2.**

For the counter-examples found by Oleg567 to the original proposition, if,

$$a=1,\quad \text{so}\quad b,c = p^2+1,\;q^2+1\tag3$$

$$\begin{aligned}
a b-1\; &= p^2\\ 
a c-1\; &= q^2\\
\color{brown}{b c-1} \; &= p^2+q^2+p^2q^2\\
a b - a - b + c \; &= q^2\\
b c + a - b - c  \; &=  p^2q^2\\ 
a c - a + b - c  \; &=  p^2\\ 
 \end{aligned}$$

If $q=2p^2$, then $\color{brown}{b c-1}$ also becomes a square. However, the remaining three numbers will *not* necessarily be so.

**III. Summary**

It is asked, "*For $2\leq a < b < c$, if the six numbers are perfect squares, then are the three (remaining) numbers perfect squares?"*.

I assume that the six expressions being squares are ***not sufficient***, by themselves, to ensure that the remaining three expressions will be also squares (like Oleg's counter-examples). The fact that for $a>1$ the remaining three numbers were squares seem to be more due to the additional condition $(1)$.

But it would be interesting to find $a,b,c$ with $a>1$ such that ***only*** the first six numbers are squares.

Comment: That's very interesting! I added proposition 2,3,4. Proposition 4 comes from your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @mathlove: It's ok. However, I corrected a small detail. The condition also works if $a=1$, but it uses a different $c$ from Oleg's original counter-examples.

Comment: @mathlove: My guess is that when $\color{red}{1}<a<b<c$ and there is a solution to, $$\begin{aligned}ab-1\; &= x_1^2\\ac-1\; &= x_2^2\\bc-1\; &= x_3^2\end{aligned}$$ then $a,b,c\,$ **always** satisfies, $$(a+b+c)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2+2)$$ I'm willing to bet 50 points to anyone who can answer a counter-example. :)

Comment: @mathlove: My guess was wrong. I've extended my search radius and found there _are_ some $a,b,c$ such that the first three expressions are squares but do not belong to either Assumption 1 or 2, like $$2,\;5,\;925$$ $$5,\;65,\;4033$$ which do **not** satisfy $(a+b+c)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2+2).$

Comment: I simplified proposition 4. I hope I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I crossposted this question to [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196609/conjectures-on-perfect-squares).

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that we know **proposition 2 and 4 are true** from a comment by a user duje on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196609/conjectures-on-perfect-squares).

From Lemma 7 of [this paper](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/dioeul2.pdf) duje showed in his comment, we can say

> If each of
>   $$ab-1,\ \ bc-1,\ \ ca-1$$
>   is a perfect square and $0\lt a\lt b\lt c\lt 3ab\in\mathbb Z$, then $c=a+b+2\sqrt{ab-1}$ holds.

By adding Tito Piezas III's findings to this result, we can say

> If each of
>   $$ab-1,\ \ bc-1,\ \ ca-1$$
>   is a perfect square and $0\lt a\lt b\lt c\lt 3ab\in\mathbb Z$, then each of $$ab\mp (a+ b-c),\ bc\mp (b+ c- a),\ ca\mp (c+ a-b)$$
>   is a perfect square.

Then, duje pointed that since $1\le a\lt b\lt c,ab+a+b-c\ge 0\Rightarrow c\lt 3ab,$ we can say that proposition 2 and 4 are true.