# why this $ab+k,bc+k,ca+k$ always perfect square

Tags: number-theory

let prime number $p$ such $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$,and $p|k$,show that:there exist  infinitely many triples $(a,b,c)$ of postive integers such that $a,b,c$ are in arithmetic progression,and $ab+k,bc+k,ca+k$ are perfect square.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1057324_the_system_is_almost_linear_diophantine_equations

Comment: but your result can't solve this problem,Thank you

Comment: You need to use the formula and choose the right solution.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120391/clever-use-of-pells-equation/1137422#1137422