Ensuring $xy +1$, $xu +1$, $xv +1$, $yu+1$, $yv +1$, $uv +1$ all are perfect squares
Prove that there are infinitely many quadruples $(x,y,u,v)$ of positive integers such that $xy +1$, $xu +1$, $xv +1$, $yu+1$, $yv +1$, $uv +1$ are all perfect squares.
My Attempt
I thought of using a parametric approach inspired by Pythagorean triples. I started by defining the variables as follows:
$x = 2mn, \quad y = m^2 - n^2, \quad u = m^2 + n^2, \quad v = 2m^2$,
where  $m$ and $n$  are positive integers. My goal was to verify if this choice of $x, y, u, v $ works for all the expressions.
1. For  $xy + 1$ , substituting  $x = 2mn$ and  $y = m^2 - n^2$ , I get:
$xy + 1 = (2mn)(m^2 - n^2) + 1 = 2mn(m^2 - n^2) + 1$.
At first glance, this expression seems complicated, but I thought it might reduce to a perfect square with a suitable choice of  $m$  and  $n$ . For instance, setting  $m = 2$ and  $n = 1$ , I get:
$xy + 1 = 2(2)(1)(4 - 1) + 1 = 12 + 1 = 13$,
which isn't a perfect square. So, I kept thinking there must be a better choice of $m$  and $n$ .
2. For  $xu + 1$ , using  $u = m^2 + n^2$ , I got:
$xu + 1 = (2mn)(m^2 + n^2) + 1 = 2mn(m^2 + n^2) + 1$.
Again, for  $m = 2$ and  $n = 1$ , this becomes:
$xu + 1 = 2(2)(1)(4 + 1) + 1 = 20 + 1 = 21$,
which is not a perfect square either. So I tried different values, but couldn't find a combination that worked.
3. For $xv + 1$ , using  $v = 2m^2$ , I got:
$xv + 1 = (2mn)(2m^2) + 1 = 4m^3n + 1$.
For  $m = 2$ and  $n = 1$ , this gives:
$xv + 1 = 4(2^3)(1) + 1 = 32 + 1 = 33$,
again not a perfect square.
Stuck Point:
While the parametric forms seemed promising, I haven't been able to find values of $m$ and  $n$  that make all the expressions perfect squares simultaneously. I was wondering if this parametrization needs adjustment, or if there's another method I could use.
How can I proceed further? Are there better parametric forms or some identities I'm overlooking?

Why do you assume that $x^2+y^2=u^2$ is a Pythagorean triple? There is more a relation to Pell's equation, see here.

Which is the source of the problem? (Passing to complicated families of special values for $x,y,\dots$ that do not work by design is not an attempt to solve the problem.)

Where do you get these questions?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1120391/1296310

As Dietrich suggested:   take the (positive) $x$    values in $3x^2 - 2 = z^2.$ These are in the squence
$$  1, 3, 11, 41, 153, 571, 2131, 7953, 29681, 110771, 413403, 1542841,...$$
which obey $  x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n.$  Put another way,
$$ x_{n+1}^2 - x_n x_{n+2} = -2 $$
Then take a consecutive pair $x_n, x_{n+1}$ and form quadruple
$$ \left( \; 1, \; 3, \; x_n^2 - 1, \; x_{n+1}^2 - 1  \; \right)  $$
Note that  $  x_{n+1}^2 - 4 x_{n+1} x_n + x_n^2 = -2,  $  proved below, demonstrates our main comparison:
$$ 1 + (x_n^2 - 1)(x_{n+1}^2 - 1)  = (x_n x_{n+1} -2)^2 $$
Some of the necessary tools are in How to prove each element of the following sequence is a perfect square?
$$  
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1}^2 \\
x_{n+1} x_{n+2} \\
x_{n+2}^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
1 & -8 & 16
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n}^2 \\
x_{n} x_{n+1} \\
x_{n+1}^2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1}^2 \\
x_{n+1} x_{n+2} \\
x_{n+2}^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
1 & -8 & 16
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n}^2 \\
x_{n} x_{n+1} \\
x_{n+1}^2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
However
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
1 & -8 & 16
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so that
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1}^2 \\
x_{n+1} x_{n+2} \\
x_{n+2}^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n}^2 \\
x_{n} x_{n+1} \\
x_{n+1}^2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
or
$$ x_{n+2}^2 - 4 x_{n+2} x_{n+1} + x_{n+1}^2  = x_{n+1}^2 - 4 x_{n+1} x_n + x_n^2 .  $$
Then induction shows that
$$  x_{n+1}^2 - 4 x_{n+1} x_n + x_n^2 = -2  $$

(Elaborating on Guruprasad's comment) In the linked post, it is showed that if we have a 3-variable solution such that $ 1 + xy, 1+yz , 1+zx$ are all perfect squares, then we can define 2 integers $ s_\pm = x+y+z + 2xyz \pm 2\sqrt{ (xy+1)(yz+1)(zx+1) }$ for which $1+s_\pm x , 1 + s_\pm y, 1+s_\pm z$ are also all perfect squares.
If we select the positive version, then we're always guaranteed to get a positive integer, that is larger than the rest.
Now, we can start with $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, n)$ for any positive integer $n$, to generate the sequence
$$ a_{i+3} = a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} + 2a_i a_{i+1}a_{i+2} + 2 \sqrt{ (a_i a_{i+1} +1 ) ( a_{i+1} a_{i+2} + 1  ( a_{i+2} a_i + 1 ) }. $$
The first few terms are $0, 0, n, n+2, 2n^2 + 8n + 4, \ldots  $
Then, any 4 consecutive terms satisfy the conditions of the problem.
As an explicit example, with $n = 1$, we get $0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 120, 11781, \ldots $

Such quadruples are known in literature as $D(1)$-quadruples. `Everybody' knows that for any $D(1)$-triple $(x,y,z)$, the formula $s_+$ provides the only extension to a quadruple by an element greater than $\max {x,y,z}$. Helas, nobody knows how to prove it. Further details are found on Dujella's page or in his recent book
